# Batch Can you use findstr with an if statement

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, uppercase, findstr, errorlevel

I am trying to test if a string is uppercase. I know that this works:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set X=A
set Y=a

echo !X!|findstr "^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*$"
echo !errorlevel!
echo !Y!|findstr "^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*$"
echo !errorlevel!
```

and this results with an `errorlevel` of 1 if it isn't uppercase, but I would like to find out if it is uppercase without the `echo` portion, like using an `if` statement. But I don't know how to use the `findstr` and pass it a variable to test, so that it can result with an `errorlevel` I can test in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need ECHO, but you don't need to test ERRORLEVEL. You can use `&&` to test if the preceding command failed, or `||` to test if it failed. You also can redirect FINDSTR to nul, since you don't need to see the output.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set X=A
set Y=a

for %%V in (X Y) do echo(!%%V!|findstr "^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*$" >nul && (
  echo !%%V! is all upper case
) || (
  echo !%%V! is not all upper case
)
```

Everything could be put on one line, but I used parentheses and multiple lines for readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem this bat only validates one character.

set Y=a

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('echo !Y!^|findstr "^[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*$"') do set output=%%i

if [%output%]==[] (echo !Y! is lower case) else (echo !Y! is upper case)

rem Expected output: a is lower case
```

Because It is using findstr.

```
findstr/?
Searches for strings in files.

FINDSTR [/B] [/E] [/L] [/R] [/S] [/I] [/X] [/V] [/N] [/M] [/O] [/P] [/F:file]
        [/C:string] [/G:file] [/D:dir list] [/A:color attributes] [/OFF[LINE]]
        strings [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]
```

If a new text file containing [a-z] is not created, the ECHO portion may be unavoidable. 
I slightly modify the code to avoid echo out unnecessary information.

Comment: Regular expressions `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]` _should_ match upper- and lower-case letters, respectively, **but** following [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868) this does not work properly due to a bug of `findstr`...

Comment: Thank You. I just realised this bug. The answer is modified.

Comment: Ah, and there is no meta character `+` for `findstr`, you can only use `*`; to achieve a one-or-more-matches functionality, you need to state `??*` (meaning one or more `?`s)...

Comment: Modified. There are still quite some limitations in this bat.